# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pydantic_core'

Tags: aws-lambda, pydantic

Getting the following error on testing AWs lambda created by uploading zip.
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pydantic_core'"

zip is created on macOS. I can see that it has downloaded a wheel pydantic_core-2.16.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl. Is this an issue?

How to ensure that I have the correct wheel compatible with AWS lambda.